# Radio station thumbnail and category image not showing in Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Title: Radio station thumbnail and category image not showing in Android Studio project

Hello,

I'm facing an issue with my Android Studio project where the radio station thumbnail and category image are not showing in the app. The project uses the Glide library to load the images from the server. However, when I run the app, the images are not displayed.

I have checked the following:

1. Verified that the image URLs are correct and accessible. The URLs are constructed using `sharedPref.getBaseUrl()` for the base URL and `c.category_image` for the image path.
2. Ensured that the image files exist on the server and can be accessed via a web browser or network debugging tool like Postman.
3. Confirmed that the necessary internet permissions are declared in the app's manifest file.

Despite these checks, the images are still not loading. Additionally, I noticed that when I open the image URL in an incognito mode or private browsing session, the images are also not displayed.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my `AdapterCategory` class:

```java
// (Include the code snippet from your AdapterCategory class here)


Glide.with(context)
    .load(sharedPref.getBaseUrl() + "/upload/category/" + c.category_image.replace(" ", "%20"))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
    .thumbnail(0.3f)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(vItem.imgCategory);
```